# Linux phpmyadmin when accesing localhost/phpmyadmin see only text

Tags: php, html, linux, phpmyadmin, apache2

I have problem with accessing phpmyadmin i can access but it's show me just text, there is no decompilation of php sending screen

[image]

Comment: I think that in file missing php tags, but i don't know where that file is.

Comment: I found that file and php tags not missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, i had installed php7.2 and i disabled the php version through the command

`a2dismod php7.2`

and this happend.

Then i ran the below command

```
a2enmod php7.2
```

and i'm done.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the mod_php, the php interpreter:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then obviously restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Yes there missed some php modules.